# Locating ground and other pins on circuit board

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, remote-control, hacking

I am a beginner attempting to learn how to hack RC cars like is demonstrated in [this](https://youtu.be/aP38w8qssXU) video.

My problem is I can't spot the ground pin and the other pins related to the wheel drive functions except I randomly test pins with my multimeter.

In an old pair of RC cars, after a long time of trial and error I finally located the ground and one of the pins connected to a wheel.

**However, I just wonder if there is a technique for locating ground and other pins in a circuit, please?**

I want to learn how to locate the relevant pins so I can hack these [cars](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mercedes-Radio-Controlled-Race-Pack/dp/B06WP2SQTB/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?s=kids&ie=UTF8&qid=1520529461&sr=1-1-fkmr1&keywords=BMW%20vs%20Mercedes%20Twin%20Pack%20RC%20Cars).

Comment: The "ground" is usually connected to the `-` terminal of the battery. Then you just check continuity with that point.

Comment: data-sheets for the parts involved will also indicate ground... the black wire to the servo is ground...